# Integral of an interior product is 0

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Here is a question about problem 3.12 from Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry. $M$ is a compact orientable and connected Riemannian $n$ manifold. $f$ is a differentiable function on $M$ such that $\Delta f\ge 0$.Let $X$ be the gradient of $f$. $v$ is the volume form on $M$ and $i(X)v$ denotes the interior product of $X$ and $v$. We want to show $\Delta f=0$.  In the hint given by him, there is an identity
$$\int_M\  \Delta fv=\int_MdivXv=\int_M d(i(X)v)=\int_{\partial M}i(X)v=0$$
Where $div Xv= d(i(X)v)$ is obtained in a previous problem. The third equality is by Stokes theorem. I have no idea why the last equality holds. Any help  will be appreciated.

Comment: Is $M$ a manifold or a manifold with boundary?

Comment: @Thomas The context does not indicate whether or not it has boundary. Is it true for M with boundary?

Comment: This question would be trivial for manifolds without boundary. This is not true for all $X$ (consider the case that $X$ is an outward pointing normal on the boundary), so the gradient assumption is important.

Comment: I've put some context of the problem.

Comment: Isn't $M = [0,1]$, $f(x)=x^2$ a counterexample?

Comment: I'm pretty sure no boundary is allowed, so the last equality is because $\partial M = 0$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis You are right and you have already given a counterexample. Some authors use compact in the sense of "compact and without boundary" and if I remember correctly, Do Carmo is one of those using this terminology/

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis，@Markus Heinrich Thank you so much.